# How do I save files from Google Colab to Google Drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm doing some image manipulation, and I'm able to download the images, but trying to figure out how to save the images directly to google drive.

```
  mask_out=cv2.subtract(rgb,img)
  mask_out=cv2.subtract(rgb,mask_out)
  mask_out[rgb == [20, 0, 25]] = 255
  cv2.imwrite('out4.jpeg' , mask_out)
  cv2_imshow(mask_out)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.imwrite('res.png' , mask_out)    
  files.download('res.png')
```

you can see from the code that the desired image exists within the mask-out variable. It's easy enough to read files from Drive in Colab but I can't find the docs on saving files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you have to share a google drive folder in "edit" mode, for example:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wNJUZtQD_6oBvvUhWRlAb0xjjjoLZQ?usp=sharing
(the link is not valid, it's just an example)

The id you need to copy into the code is: `1wNJUZtQD_6oBvvUhWRlAb0xjjjoLZQ`

```py
!pip install --upgrade gupload

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from google.colab import auth

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()

!gupload --to '1wNJUZtQD_6oBvvUhWRlAb0xjjjoLZQ' res.png

# if multiple images
# !gupload --to '1wNJUZtQD_6oBvvUhWRlAb0xjjjoLZQ' *.png
```

Comment: That worked great thanks, how do I make res.png a variable aka I'm calling this function recursively with a different filename each time

Comment: i think you should use regular expressions

Answer (score 23):

Easy way to save is to mount google drive and provide path to the folder in drive where files need to be saved.

#### Mount Drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

#### Generate Random Image and show

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

rgb_img = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(400,400,3), dtype=np.uint8)

#cv2.imshow('RGB', rgb_img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2_imshow(rgb_img)
```

#### Save image to drive directly

Path to save in drive can be found easily by clicking `files` on left side, navigating to folder and right click to choose `Copy path`. This will save the image to folder named `Delete` in Google Drive.

```
# Save Image
cv2.imwrite('/content/drive/My Drive/Delete/res.png' , rgb_img)
```

#### Using copy command

This was not asked but can be useful. Assuming `/content/res.png` is image path and `/content/drive/My Drive/Delete` is destination.

Alternate option is write image in colab and copy to drive using `!cp "/content/res.png" "/content/drive/My Drive/Delete"` after drive mount.

Answer (score 6):

**Mount Drive**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

**Copy all Content to Drive**

```
!cp -r "/content/yolov5" "/content/drive/MyDrive"
```